# Formula to add 4 hours within business hours

Tags: formula

My business requirement is to show SLA(SLA is a custom formula field under cases) as 4 hours within business hours. Our business hours are 8.30AM to 5.30PM CST.

**Requirement**:

1. If any case opened before 8.30AM it should show 12.30PM as SLA
2. If a case opened at 9AM it should show 1PM as SLA.
3. If a case opened at 1PM it should show 5MP as SLA.
4. If a case opened at 3:30PM it should show next working day(exclude Saturday, Sunday)10.30 AM  as SLA.
5. If a case opened after 5.30PM it should show SLA next working day(exclude Saturday, Sunday)12.30Pm as SLA.

**Issues**:

1. It's considering the business hours as 8AM to 7PM instead of 8.30AM to 5.30PM.
2. Within business hours it's not adding 4 hours SLA.

Here's my formula::

```
IF(  
  ISNULL( SetSLA__c),  
  null,  
  DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(DATEVALUE( SetSLA__c+  
if(OR(VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(TEXT(SetSLA__c),9)),2)))>=24,VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(TEXT(SetSLA__c),9)),2)))<5),1,0)+  

CASE( MOD(DATEVALUE(SetSLA__c)- DATE(1900, 1, 7),7),   
6,2,   
0,1,  
0)))
&" "  
&RPAD(  
if(VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(TEXT(SetSLA__c),9)),2)))>=24,'00:00:00',  
if(VALUE(TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(TEXT(SetSLA__c),9)),2)))  <13,'17:30:00',TRIM(LEFT(TRIM(RIGHT(TEXT(SetSLA__c),9)),8)))),8)  
))
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE; I'd suggest for readability to do this in Flow (or better yet, Apex) as you can decompose into each use case with nice comments/labels

Comment: I agree, the best way to do this is in Flow/Process Builder. I understand @cropredy's APEX but, as you can break up the formula into different actions with comments in the Descriptions, APEX may be too much overhead